# Generics : Error while passing multiple classes , interface in bounded types

Tags: java, generics

```
class A<T extends Number & Runnable> {

...

}

A<Thread> a = new A<Thread>();
A<Runnable> a1 = new A<Runnable>();
A<Integer> a2 = new A<Integer>();
```

Conceptually I should be able to pass the classes which `enter code here`are implementing Runnable as well as extending Number , but I am getting compile time error which says Bound mismatch , what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of `Thread`, `Runnable` and `Integer` satisfy both of your type bounds, which require a sub-class of `Number` that also implements the `Runnable` interface.

Therefore none of your three attempts to instantiate `A` passes compilation.

If you create a sub-class of `Number` that implements `Runnable`, you would be able to use it with your `A` class.

For example:

```
class MyNumber extends Number implements Runnable 
{
    ...
}
```

This will pass compilation:

```
A<MyNumber> a = new A<MyNumber>();
```

Comment: I am hoping this was a contrived example. Please don't create a class that implements both `Number` and `Runnable`. Or if you do, come back and explain to us why that was necessary.

Comment: yeah it was contrived , just to understand the concept.